# The Lagrangian one more time

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Until now, every tentative to create a function which solves analytically a constrained optimization problem fails to be general because if it works for analytical functions it fails for transcendental ones.

I was imagining to give the good substitution to help Mathematica to solve the first order conditions when there is a trick. I have constructed the following code :

```
   ClearAll["Global`"]
u1[x_, y_, z_] := x^α y^β z^γ
u2[x_, y_, z_] := x y z
u3[x_, y_, z_] := α Log[x] + β Log[y] + γ Log[z]
u4[x_, y_, 
    z_] := (α x^((s - 1)/s) + β y^((s - 1)/
            s) + γ z^((s - 1)/s))^(s/(s - 1))

u[x_, y_, z_] := u3[x, y, z]

con[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Subscript[p, 1] x + Subscript[p, 2] y +  Subscript[p, 3] z
l[x_, y_, z_, λ_] := 
  u[x, y, z] - λ (con[x, y, z] - R)
ll = Simplify[
   Grad[l[x, y, z, λ], {x, y, 
      z, λ}] //. {x_^(-1 + α_)
              y_^β_ z_^γ_ -> α A/x}];
Solve[ll == {0, 0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z, λ}]
```

When I replace with u1,  u2, u3 the code works fine --- it's normal for u2 and u3 since there is no need for substitution. But, with u4 the substitution is not effective.

1) is there a way to remedy this problem and to help Mathematica in all the non-algebraic cases;

2) the code is for functions of 3 arguments. How to define a function for an arbitrary number of variables which will do the job.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as pasted. Perhaps the code gets mangled because of the special formatting. Could you fix that? See also [this Meta post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: MarcoB, my code was working on version 11.0.1. But  I have erased all special formattings  as you have required.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: m_Goldberg I do not understand your proposal to close this question. This is an important topic for economists who use Mathematica. Some presentations or articles on Mathematica says that they can solve constrained optimization. But when one try to use classical functions used in this field for which one knows a solution (obtained with a pencil) Mathematica fails mainly because there are  transcendental elements in the problem. I was thinking that it was legitimate to ask others if they have found a way to find a solution.

Comment: Why is the solution for `Solve[u3[x, y, z] == {0, 0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z, \[Lambda]}]` acceptable, but `Solve[u4[x, y, z] == {0, 0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z, \[Lambda]}]` not? You can use `u5[x__]:=` for an arbitrary number of variables.

Comment: Feyre this is not the problem. In the contrary to the case u1, where the writing the derivatives as $\alpha_i U/x_i$ does the trick since $x_i$ has power 1, with $U_4$ the substitution involve $x_i^{\alpha_i}$ and obviously it is not computed. I was obliged to prepare a course today, but I will try to give a partial resolution of this problem. Partial because, I hope to be able to cope with each problem in turn but I do not know how to construct only one command say $lagrangian[u, cons_1, cons_2,..., \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots]$